# Ruby on Rails Email Booking Information

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email

I am creating a booking cinema site in `Ruby on Rails`. A user can currently book a showing of a film and a quantity of seats for that showing. This is saved in the bookings table, but what I want to do is get it so that when a booking is made the user receives an email detailing the booking. This email should contain the film title, the show date, the show time, the screen, and the number of adult seats, child seats, student seats, and senior seats.

This is the schema:

```
create_table "bookings", force: :cascade do |t|
t.integer  "user_id"
t.integer  "showing_id"
t.datetime "created_at",     null: false
t.datetime "updated_at",     null: false
t.integer  "adult_seats"
t.integer  "child_seats"
t.integer  "senior_seats"
t.integer  "student_seats"
end

create_table "films", force: :cascade do |t|
t.string   "title"
t.string   "synopsis"
t.string   "director"
t.string   "cast1"
t.string   "cast2"
t.string   "cast3"
t.date     "release_date"
t.string   "warnings"
t.datetime "created_at",     null: false
t.datetime "updated_at",     null: false
t.string   "image_url"
t.string   "certificate_id"
t.integer  "category_id"
t.integer  "hours"
t.integer  "minutes"
t.string   "video_url"
end

create_table "screens", force: :cascade do |t|
t.string   "name"
t.datetime "created_at", null: false
t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
end

create_table "showings", force: :cascade do |t|
t.date     "show_date"
t.time     "show_time"
t.integer  "film_id"
t.datetime "created_at", null: false
t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
t.integer  "screen_id"
end

create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
t.string   "password_digest"
t.string   "role"
t.datetime "created_at",      null: false
t.datetime "updated_at",      null: false
t.string   "first_name"
t.string   "last_name"
t.string   "house_no"
t.string   "street"
t.string   "town"
t.string   "postcode"
t.string   "email"
t.date     "date_of_birth"
end
```

New and Create methods in the bookings_controller:

```
def new
  @booking = Booking.new(showing_id: params[:showing_id], user_id: User.find(session[:user_id]).id, adult_seats: params[:adult_seats], child_seats: params[:child_seats], senior_seats: params[:senior_seats], student_seats: params[:student_seats])
end

def create
@booking = Booking.new(booking_params)

respond_to do |format|
  if @booking.save
    format.html { redirect_to @booking, notice: 'Booking was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @booking }
  else
    format.html { render :new }
    format.json { render json: @booking.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
end
```

Can someone please tell me how I can achieve this?

**UPDATE**

After following http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html as recommended to me I have now got the following files:

***application_mailer.rb:***

```
class ApplicationMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default "from@example.com"
  layout 'mailer'
end
```

***user_mailer.rb:***

```
class UserMailer < ApplicationMailer
  default from: 'notifications@example.com'

  def welcome_email(user)
    @user = user
    @url  = 'http://localhost:3000/users/login'
    mail(to: @user.email, subject: 'Welcome to My Awesome Site')
  end
end
```

***views/user_mailer/welcome_email.html.erb:***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' http-equiv='Content-Type' />
  </head>
    <body>
    <h1>Welcome to example.com, <%= @user.name %></h1>
    <p>
      You have successfully signed up to example.com,
      your username is: <%= @user.login %>.<br>
    </p>
    <p>
      To login to the site, just follow this link: <%= @url %>.
    </p>
    <p>Thanks for joining and have a great day!</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

***views/user_mailer/welcome_email.txt.erb***

```
Welcome to example.com, <%= @user.name %>
===============================================

You have successfully signed up to example.com,
your username is: <%= @user.login %>.

To login to the site, just follow this link: <%= @url %>.

Thanks for joining and have a great day!
```

And the create method in users_controller:

```
def create
  @user = User.new(user_params)
if @user.save
  # login is achieved by saving a user's 'id' in a session variable, 
  # accessible to all pages
   UserMailer.welcome_email(@user).deliver_later
  session[:user_id] = @user.id
  redirect_to films_path
else
  render action: "new"
end
end
```

But I get the error:

> TypeError in UsersController#create 
>       can't convert String into Hash

Any ideas?

Comment: Hi Ben, not sure if you've sorted this by now but when exactly do you get the error?

Comment: Why are you showing code from `bookings_controller`, if you error explicitly mentions `users_controller`?